# Implementing custom claim with extended MVC Core Identity user

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

How can I create a custom authorize claim in MVC Core 2.0 (using AspNetCore.identity) to verify a custom user boolean property?  I have extended the IdentityUser (ApplicationUser) to include a boolean value "IsDeveloper". I am using claims based authentication and would like to add a custom claim, but am not certain where to start.  How can I create a custom claim that will:

1. Find the current (customized) Core.Identity user.
2. Evaluate the a custom identity user bool value?

I understand the core identity claims [MSDN: Claims Based Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims), but am new to custom claims, so I am not sure where to begin. The Online documents that I have found do not work or does not fit my scenario.

Comment: I found this link very useful for asp.net core 2.0+: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/add-extra-user-claims-in-asp-net-core-web-applications-1f28c98c9ec6

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74684370/7186739

Answer (score 30, accepted):

So, you need to create custom claims somewhere and then check it through a custom policy or manually.

## 1) Custom claims adding

#### JwtBearer authentication

You can do something like this:

In your controller action that returns jwt-token you can add your `custom claim`:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public dynamic GetToken(string login, string password)
{
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    var sec = "12312313212312313213213123123132123123132132132131231313212313232131231231313212313213132123131321313213213131231231213213131311";
    var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sec));
    var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

    var user = GetUserFromDb(login);
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(user.Email), new[] { new Claim("user_id", user.Id) });
    if (user.IsDeveloper)
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("IsDeveloper", "true"));
    var token = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(subject: identity,
                                                signingCredentials: signingCredentials,
                                                audience: "ExampleAudience",
                                                issuer: "ExampleIssuer",
                                                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(100));
    return handler.WriteToken(token);
}
```

#### ASP.NET Core Identity authentication

You need to implement a custom `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory` or use `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` as a base class:

```cs
public class ApplicationClaimsIdentityFactory: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory <ApplicationUser>
{
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    public ApplicationClaimsIdentityFactory(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor):base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
    {}
    public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
        if (user.IsDeveloper)
        {
            ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[] {
                new Claim("IsDeveloper", "true")
            });
        }
        return principal;
    }
}
```

then you need to register it in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, ApplicationClaimsIdentityFactory>();
```

## 2) Check the claim

#### Custom policy

In `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Developer", policy =>
                        policy.RequireClaim("IsDeveloper", "true"));
});
```

and protect your action for developers:

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = "Developer"), HttpGet]
public string DeveloperSecret()
{
    return "Hello Developer"
}
```

#### Check the claim manually

Somewhere in the controller:

```cs
bool isDeveloper = User.Claims.Any(c => c.Type == "IsDeveloper" && c.Value == "true")
```

If you are using some other authentication the idea should be the same.

Comment: thanks, the ApplicationClaimsIdentityFactory is a must have, I just have to adapt to work with dotnet core 2.1 but it was just a litle change at the signature of the constructor.

Comment: I'd recommend overriding `GenerateClaimsAsync` instead of `CreateAsync`. There'll be no need to cast `principal.Identity` to `ClaimsIdentity` then

Answer (score 0):

Add Custom Value in Claim in .NET 6

```
new Claim("AdminStatusIS", AdminStatus.ToString()
```

And then use it in Program.cs

```
policy.RequireClaim("AdminStatusIs", "True");
```