# How to add custom claims types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

```
var ManagerAccess = context.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.System).Value;
```

Here I want to execute like this:
`(claimstypes.ManagerAccess).value;`

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Are you using JWT or ASP.NET Identity? Have you tried something that didn't work, and what was it?

Comment: When and where do you want to add custom claims types?Besides,`Claimstypes` is static class you could not use `Claimstypes.ManagerAccess`, could you use `context.Principal.FindFirst("ManagerAccess").Value`?

Comment: .AddJwtBearer(x => { x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents {               OnTokenValidated = context =>{                       
///this are standard format from claimtypes
var name = int.Parse(context.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value);
///but i want to add my custom claimtypes like manager access and an other types based on my requirments..
var managerAccess = context.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.managerAccess).Value;
 var claims = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Claim>{                                    new Claim("demo1", demo1)};
var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

Answer (score 0):

To add custom claim type, you could use `IClaimsTransformation`

```
public class CustomClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("ManagerAccess", "MyValue"));
        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

Register in startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, CustomClaimsTransformer>();
```

Check you claims:

```
var ManagerAccess = context.Principal.FindFirst("ManagerAccess").Value;
```

For more solutions, refer to [Implementing custom claim with extended MVC Core Identity user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48652426/implementing-custom-claim-with-extended-mvc-core-identity-user)